# Count number of times text is repeated in a spreadsheet (excel)

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with this kind of data:

[image: Raw Data]

I would like to count the number of times the same text has appeared before in the spreadsheet. For Example if "Charlie" has been mentioned three times, the first time it appears it will show "1", the second time "2", the third time "3" and so on.
The end result I am looking for would be something like this:

[image: Final count of data]

Comment: Where would you like these numbers to show since all the data is side by side?  Have you done a search on the COUNTIF and COUNTIFS functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to combine several combinations of Countif and add them all up

In the result sheet:

A1 and copied down:

`=COUNTIF(Data!$A$1:A1,Data!A1)`

B1 and copied down:

`=COUNTIF(Data!$A$1:$A$7,Data!B1)+COUNTIF(Data!$B$1:B1,Data!B1)`

C1 and copied down:

```
=COUNTIF(Data!$A$1:$A$7,Data!C1)+COUNTIF(Data!$B$1:$B$7,Data!C1)+COUNTIF(Data!$C$1:C1,Data!C1)
```